# Referencing a drop down menu in jQuery from ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is a newbie question. I've been using jQuery for a day or so.

I simply want to capture each change in a drop down menu.

Here's my drop down menu and reference:

```
 <script src="Scripts/insertRootCauseElements.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListRootCause" runat="server" > </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here's my handler:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    //    var selectedValue = $('#DropDownListRootCause').selectedValue;
    //var selectedIndex = $('#DropDownListRootCause').selectedIndex;
    alert("HERE");
    $('#DropDownListRootCause').change(function () {
    alert("Changed " + $('#DropDownListRootCause').selectedIndex);
})
.change();
//    if ($('#DropDownListRootCause').change) {
//        alert("dd change " + selectedIndex);
//    }


})
```

I've tried a lot of variations but nothing is working for me. On debugging, it seems my jQuery doesn't know what "DropDownListRootCause" is.

I set AutoPostBack=true in my dd control which finds my jQuery but

```
$('#DropDownListRootCause').change(function () {
    alert("Changed " + $('#DropDownListRootCause').selectedIndex);
})
```

Still evals to false.

I added DropDownListRootCause to 'Watch' when debugging which reveals 'DropDownListRootCause' is undefined'. I've tried double and single quotes but no luck.

It must be something simple but I can't see it. Can someone help?

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle of your example ?

Answer (score 2):

If you notice in your source HTML, ASP.Net changes the ID a great deal.  A lot of times, it'll end up looking something like: `$ctr001_DropDownListRootCause`.  This is why your selector isn't working.

There are two ways to select your `select` menu correctly:

1. `$('[id$="DropDownListRootCause"]')`  This is doing an [attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).
2. `$('#<%=DropDownListRootCause.ClientID %>')`  ASP.Net will write out that full id into your selector.  **NOTE**: you can only use this when your javascript is INSIDE your `.aspx` file.  If you try to use this in a `.js` file, it won't work, as ASP.Net doesn't do anything with those files when rendering the page.

Also, the ends with selector can be modified to be more specific:

`$('select[id$="DropDownListRootCause"]')`

Edit:

There are pitfalls to the ends with selector.  If this `select` element is inside a `GridView` row, or a `Repeater`, the selector will match them all.  Say you have this `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListRootCause" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

(I've removed fluff from it)  It'll generate HTML that looks something like this:

```
<tr onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;gv&#39;,&#39;Select$0&#39;)">
    <td>
        <select name="gv$ctl03$DropDownListRootCause" id="gv_DropDownListRootCause_0"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;gv&#39;,&#39;Select$1&#39;)">
    <td>
        <select name="gv$ctl04$DropDownListRootCause" id="gv_DropDownListRootCause_1"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;gv&#39;,&#39;Select$2&#39;)">
    <td>
        <select name="gv$ctl05$DropDownListRootCause" id="gv_DropDownListRootCause_2"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;gv&#39;,&#39;Select$3&#39;)">
    <td>
        <select name="gv$ctl06$DropDownListRootCause" id="gv_DropDownListRootCause_3"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;gv&#39;,&#39;Select$4&#39;)">
    <td>
        <select name="gv$ctl07$DropDownListRootCause" id="gv_DropDownListRootCause_4"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Again, I've removed a lot of the markup that isn't needed to show what I'm talking about.  With that rendered HTML, using `$('[id$="DropDownListRootCause"]')` will select **5** `select` elements.  If you are trying to wire up the same event code to all 5 elements, you're fine.  BUT, if you're trying to do something with only **one** of them, you'll need to make the selector more specific.